# UT not pass due to undefined FormArray control while the control must be defined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have a workshop-edit component that (in order):

- Build the form
- Retrieve the workshop to edit
- Update form values with workshop values

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.buildForms();
  this.initialize();
}

async initialize(): Promise<void> {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

  this.workshop = await this.workshopService.find(id); // in real this is in a trycatch block
  this.updateFormValues();
}

buildForms(): void {
  this.form = ... // not important, this is not the problem
  this.discussesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    array: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required),
  });
}

updateFormValues(): void {
  this.form.patchValue(this.workshop);
  this.workshop.ListDebates.forEach((discussion, index) => {
    this.addDiscussion();
    (this.discussesForm.get('array') as FormArray).at(index).patchValue({ // This line will throw error while UT.
      title: discussion.Title, description: discussion.Description, key: discussion.Key,
    });
  });
}

addDiscussion(): void {
  (this.discussesForm.get('array') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.group({
    title: [null],
    description: [null],
    key: [null],
  });
}
```

**workshop.ListDebates** look like:

```
[
  {
    Key: 1,
    Title: 'title',
    Description: 'description',
  },
]
```

So, all the code above works fine, but i'm trying to unit test the **updateFormValues** method.

This is what I tried:

```
it('should update form values', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'addDiscussion');
  component.workshop = { Title: 'fake title', ListDebates: [
    { Key: 1, Title: 'fake', Description: 'fake' },
    { Key: 2, Title: 'fake', Description: 'fake' },
  ]} as any as IColabEvent;
  component.updateFormValues();
  expect(component.form.value.Title).toEqual('fake title'); // test OK
  expect((component.discussesForm.get('array') as FormArray).controls.length).toEqual(2); // test KO, expected 0 to be 2
  expect((component.discussesForm.get('array') as FormArray).at(0).value).toEqual(...); // test KO (not runned)
});
```

Everytime I get error: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined (in the **updateFormValues** method).

I've tried lots of things (and random things like adding **fixture.detectChanges()**) but I don't find a way to fix it.

What is weird is that addDiscussion is called 2 times, so I wonder why my FormArray control is undefined.

I've console.log() some things and it look like **addDiscussion** is called but isn't pushing a group like it must does.

I repeat myself but in the real app it's working as intended.

Comment: In `updateFormValues` right before the first line, do `console.log(this.form)` and maybe `debugger` right after it. Run the test with `fit` and open the developer tools right away (pressing F12). The `debugger` should be tripped and you can see the value of `this.form` in the console. Judging by the error message, I bet `this.form` is undefined at that instance in time.

Maybe `buildForms` is not being called before directly calling `updateFormValues` in your test.

Comment: `this.form` is different `this.discussesForm`. In my test the first expect pass so it means `buildForm` is called. I'm unable to open tests withing browser (only cli) so for debuging it's kinda hard tho.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted.

Comment: I would find a way to debug using the browser or some method of debugging so it makes tasks like this easier. 

But I think I know what is the issue. In your test you are spying on `addDiscussion`. This will just create a "watcher" for that function and not actually call its implementation. To have both a "watcher" and to call the function, you can do
`spyOn(component, 'addDiscussion').and.callThrough()`. In fact, you can get rid of this `spyOn`, I don't think you need it.

Comment: Oh, i used spyOn for testing haveBeenCalledTimes(2) but i don't need it anymore now u're right.

Comment: I think to set `component.workshop` like you did in your test is not a good practice. You should be mocking `workshopService` to return the desired data in order to set `workshop`. And since the `initialize` method is `async` and you are not `await`ing it. There may be a race condition that after you setting `workshop` manually it is set again by the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than something being wrong with your test cases, it is in fact your code that has an issue. There is no need for you to use `addDiscussion` first to create an object with `null` values and then use `patchValue` to set the values. Instead, set the values as you create the form group itself. Change your `addDiscussion` function to accept the `discussion` parameter.

```js
addDiscussion(discussion = {}): void {
    this.discussesForm.get('array').push(this.formBuilder.group({
        title: discussion.Title || null,
        description: discussion.Description || null,
        key: discussion.Key || null
    }));
}
```

Then in `updateFormValues`, in your `foreach` loop, get rid of the `patchValue` code and pass `discussion` instead.

```js
this.workshop.ListDebates.forEach(discussion => {
    this.addDiscussion(discussion);
});
```

Apart from this, as already mentioned in the comments, the `addDiscussion` no longer needs to be spied upon since your test depends on it. Once this is done, your tests should be working.

Comment: Yes! Sometime I don't think that the problem come from my ts and not from my test... I just needed to add `addEmptyDiscussion()` because users may add empty line in the table ^^ Thanks.

Comment: Anytime :) it's not necessary to create a new function to add empty discussion. Instead if you just call `addDiscussion` alone without any parameters, it would be sufficient. I updated the answer so that `discussion` defaults to an empty object if you don't pass any parameters to `addDiscussion` hence creating an empty line in the table with `null` values.